# HighCharts - invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

I have created a high chart using the code from the following fiddle, but have changed the data to a java string (which pulls in fine) but get the error "uncaught syntax error: invalid or unexpected token"

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/

When i click on the error it loads this console sources and points to the "data" tag:

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Users per lesson'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Users'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Users',
        data: [
            "['Snowboarding for dummies', 1], 
['Advanced Carving 
Techniques', 1],"
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

What i am actually passing is:

```
data: [
        <%=session.getAttribute("jsTag")    %>
    ],
```

But this is creating the string with linebreaks in?

If i output the string it outputs as all on one line:

> ['Snowboarding for dummies', 1], ['Advanced Carving Techniques', 1],

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the serie data, Highcharts can't understant a Javascript string so you will need to parse the string. It should be like that :

```
...
    data: [
        ['Snowboarding for dummies', 1], 
        ['Advanced Carving Techniques', 1]
    ],
...
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8z3g1o2/)

Comment: Thanks! i am passing a java string which doesnt include line breaks but on the javascript is somehow forcing the line break for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HighChart sample code, it seems that you are trying to pass an array ( data) with a single string value.

HighCharts expects a 2D array as the data key. So if you specify:

data:[ ['Shanghai', 24.2],...]

i.e 'Shanghai' is the x-axis value and 24.2 is the y-axis value.

Now if you want to pass the data as a string, you may want to parse the string first.

```
var data=JSON.parse("[[\"Snowboarding for dummies\", 1], [\"Advanced Carving Techniques\", 1]]");
```

And then pass this data variable to the HighChart object.

All the best!